# Janusgraph not able to find suitable index for a index enabled property key

Tags: elasticsearch, gremlin, graph-databases, janusgraph, full-text-indexing

I'm working on a Janusgraph application. To improve gremlin query performance we are creating two mixed indexes, one for vertices and one for edges.

Now Janusgraph can query indexes for property keys that are created and indexed at the time of index creation i.e in the same transaction. If I'm creating and indexing a new property key in a new transaction then Janusgraph is not able to query them using indexing, instead, it does a complete graph scan.

Using Janusgeaph management API I checked that all property keys are indexed and enabled, even then Janusgraph is scanning a complete graph for querying on an indexed property key.

Is there anything I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Backend index engine -> ElasticSearch

Backend Storage -> Cassandra

Answer (score 0):

Have faced this problem once. Try to reindex the created index once (Index created in some other transaction). It worked for me. Hope it works for you too.

Please find the steps below:-

**For Reindex:**

```
    mgmt = graph.openManagement()
    i = mgmt.getGraphIndex('IndexName')
    mgmt.updateIndex(i, SchemaAction.REINDEX)
    mgmt.commit()
```

**For Enable the index:**

```
    ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'IndexName').status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call()
```

**NOTE:** if you get "false" in enabling the index, Try enabling it 2 3 times using the same command (ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'IndexName').status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call()). It would work eventually.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I was able to resolve this issue after reindexing. In the documentation, they mentioned that if a property key is already in use before the index is created then only we should do reindexing but that is not the case. If you have created a property key before index then in all such cases you will have to perform reindexing.